# How is type 1 error related to precision?

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-error

I was going through the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) of Precision and Recall and it was written that "Type II errors can be said to be the complement of Recall but Precision and Type I errors are related in a more complicated way". How are Precision(True Positives) and Type I error (False Positives) related?

Comment: Precision is affected by underlying prevalence in a way Recall is not